# RazorPay Android Integration

Tags: android, integration, payment, gateway, razorpay

**How to implement razorpay integration in android from FRAGMENT instead of ACTIVITY?**

I tried but the callback methods are not called back. There is no official documentation in razorpay site for fragment implementation as well.

Answer (score 0):

implements PaymentResultListener

in your fragment.
Example:

```
public class YourFragmentName extends Fragment implements PaymentResultListener
```

Sorry to say, i also faced same issue. Ultimately i needed to remove the payment code to fragment, then it worked.